# Does Blender Have Attributes like maya?

Tags: custom-attributes

Does Blender have anything similar to the extra attributes feature of Maya? my colleagues are using Maya and have the ability to add these attributes to tell a different piece of software what to do. but I can't seem to find if blender has anything comparable.

[image: Example of the extra attributes in maya]

[image: Example of the extra attributes tab and text enter field]

Comment: Most of the properties tabs on the right hand side have a  _Custom Properties_ section at the bottom where you can add a new properties profile, whether it be for a scene, an object, a material, etc... depending on the properties tab chosen. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: As @ChristopherBennett said, in the _Properties Editor_ you can add _Custom Properties_ to the _Scene, World, Object, Object Data, Bone, Particle System, Material_ and _Texture Properties_. The question is what you mean by "to tell a different piece of software what to do". You can access these for example in the _Shader Editor_ through the _Attribute_ node, and via Python in various ways. I guess it also depends on what you want them for.